# Ping in local network pings myself

Tags: windows, ping, local-area-network

I have two computers on my local network:

- **Laptop** `192.168.2.11` *Windows 8.1*
- **Tower** `192.168.2.10` *Windows 7*

If I use **Laptop** to ping **Tower**, which has the local IP `192.168.2.10`, I will get a result from `192.168.2.11`, which is the IP for **Laptop**. This same thing happens vice-versa.

Comment: Post the output from both pings in your question.

Comment: @joeqwerty It was just saying "Response from 192.168.2.11", when pinging 192.168.2.10. Also the issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all of my desperate, I finally thought "maybe I'll just restart my rooter" and it worked. I'm so sorry for wasting your time. Next time you have an issue like this one: Restart all the devices that are involved. :)

Comment: Sometimes those rooters just need a good restartin'.

Comment: @RyanRies My provider told me it was made for 24/7 usage, but they lied to me. :(